# gdb: print sockaddr pointer value

Tags: c++, c, gdb, strace

Currently I'm trying to deploy a network application written in C++, and it looks like it falls into infinite loop due to networking problems:

```
[isaev@feck-5 ~]$ sudo strace -p 26252 -f -e trace=network -s 10000 
[pid 26272] getpeername(30, 0x7f1699ddfb60, [28]) = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[pid 26272] getpeername(30, 0x7f1699ddfb60, [28]) = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[pid 26272] getpeername(30, 0x7f1699ddfb60, [28]) = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[pid 26272] getpeername(30, 0x7f1699ddfb60, [28]) = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[pid 26272] getpeername(30, 0x7f1699ddfb60, [28]) = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[pid 26272] getpeername(30, 0x7f1699ddfb60, [28]) = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
[pid 26272] getpeername(30, 0x7f1699ddfb60, [28]) = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)
```

I need to know which network connection does the application lack.

Assumming that I can attach to the process with `gdb`, how can I print the value of a `truct sockaddr *` ([man getpeername](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getpeername)) variable that `0x7f1699ddfb60` points to?

Comment: "downcast" and dereference it by doing `p *((sockaddr_in_or_whichever_you_use *) pointer_to_struct_sockaddr)` or  `p *((sockaddr_in_or_whichever_you_use *) 0x7f1699ddfb60)`

Comment: @cad
```(gdb) x 0x7f1699ddfb60
0x7f1699ddfb60: 0x00000002```  - it looks like integer, but not a pretty printed struct :(

Comment: @alk thank you, please post an answer, I would like to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could "downcast" and dereference the pointer (or its value) by doing

```
(gdb) p *((struct sockaddr_in_or_whichever_you_use *) pointer_to_struct_sockaddr)
```

or

```
(gdb) p *((struct sockaddr_in_or_whichever_you_use *) 0x7f1699ddfb60)
```